# get Hashmap from Method

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, program-entry-point

I'm new to Java and haven't yet learned how to create 2 separate classes and combine them and so, I end up jumbling everything in the main and you can imagine how the code end up looking not understandable, which I plan to learn later on in my course. Yet I need a solution to work with 'Methods' so my code can look cleaner and if I need to add to it or repair it wouldn't be much of a hassle.

So basically my question is whether I can use Hashmap.get from the main to get information from a hashmap that was created in a method:

```
static String createAccount(String username, String authpassword) {
    Map<String, String> newacc = new HashMap<String, String>();

}
```

This above is how the method 'would' look like and below the main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    newacc.get(username);

}
```

Is this possible and it seems that I'm having this error (which I think that the main method is not reading the hasmap created in method.

```
error: cannot find symbol
    newacc.get(username);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have more code?

Comment: The scopes should be obeyed. In your case, the `newacc` should not be recreated from each call of `createAccount` and should be available from the places where you want to use. In this case, you have to declare it as a static field like this: `private static final Map<String, String> newacc = new HashMap<>();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map you create in `createAccount()` is assigned to the local variable `newacc`. This means you lose the reference to it after the method finishes.

If you want to keep a map where you can add new accounts you could make it a field of your class:

```
class AccountManager {
    private static Map<String, String> accounts = new HashMap<>();

    static void createAccount(String username, String authpassword) {
        accounts.put(username, authpassword);
    }

    static String getAuthPassword(String username) {
        return accounts.get(username);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get the input from somewhere
        AccountManager.createAccount(username, authpassword);
        AccountManager.getAuthPassword(username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your map `newacc` will only be accessible within the `createAccount` method and not to outside world as its scope is just within the method `createAccount` and hence compilation error.

To resolve this, define `newacc` as static and at class level. So just define Map outside the method like:

```
static Map<String, String> newacc = new HashMap<String, String>();
static String createAccount(String username, String authpassword) {
    //access newacc here
}
```

And similarly you could access the same in main method directly.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be unable to access the `newacc` variable from your `main` method with your current code, because `newacc` is scoped to the `createAccount` method. You have two options, to define `newacc` as a static field in your class and access the same instance from both methods (see answer from @SMA), or to return your account from the `createAccount` method and capture it in `main`. Like so:

```
Map<String, String> createAccount(String username, String password) {
    Map<String, String> newacc = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // do stuff with account

    return newacc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> newacc = createAccount("user", "pass");
    newacc.get("username");
}
```